# Extra constraint are added by hibernate in postgres database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have defined a entity using Entity and table annotations of JPA in my spring boot project and connected with postgres database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country_user", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_name","role_name", "adhar_number"})
})
public class UserModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name ="user_name)
    private String userName;

   @Column(name="adhar_number)
   private String adharNumber;

  @Column(name="age")
  private String age;
  
  @Column(name="role_name")
  private String roleName;
}
```

After running application, 2 unique constraints are being created for country_user table in postgres db

```
constraintname                    columns
ukb5g170gsyd9h7pqfs34309lk3       user_name,role_name,adhar_number
uka5g119gpie9h7ress63129nd3       user_name,role_name
```

but there should be only 1 unique constraint as defined `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_name","role_name", "adhar_number"}`

I want only 1 unique constraint in table, not the subset of roles I defined.

Comment: How are you checking and having JPA create your constraints? I'd guess this uka5g119gpie9h7ress63129nd3  is a left over from some previous run - drop your tables or try on a clean schema.

Comment: I dropped the extra constraint from table, but when I run my application again, again 2 constraint are created

Comment: Nothing in what you've shown explains it being added, so it'll be due to something you are not showing in the application. Check you haven't put this elsewhere in your application, say on another class using the "country_user" table. That is a strange table name for an entity - could you maybe also have a User and Country class with a ManyToMany between them, or something with roles?